# how to do a reverse on a url with primary key in django

Tags: python, regex, django, http-post, django-urls

I have the following url entry for my app:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<action>add|edit)/type/$', 'customer.views.edit', name='customer-edit'),
```

I want to post to this url with a reverse.  When I do the following I get the error NoReverseMatch:

```
self.client.post(reverse('customer-edit'), {'something:'something'}, follow=True)
```

This is the full error:
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'customer-edit' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Do I need to pass args or kwargs to the reverse?  If so what would they look like to match the url above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To pass `args` to an url you can pass a variable named `args` of type `tuple` to `reverse`:

```
self.client.post(reverse('customer-edit', args=(1, 'add',)), {'something:'something'}, follow=True)
```

another problem is that the `dict` has a `Syntax Error`

```
self.client.post(reverse('customer-edit', args=(1, 'add',)), {'something' : 'something'}, follow=True)
```

Hope this helps you!